# Error when connecting web socket in elastic beanstalk

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, websocket

I create web socket using java

```
package websocket;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/ServerEndpoint")
public class ServerEndpoint{
    private static final Set<Session> SESSIONS = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        SESSIONS.add(session);
        System.out.println(session+" :connected"); 
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        SESSIONS.remove(session);
        System.out.println(session+" :closed");
    }

    public static void sendAll(String text) {
        synchronized (SESSIONS) {
            for (Session session : SESSIONS) {
                if (session.isOpen()) {
                    session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I **can** connect web socket using javascript 
if I use this link

> "ws://localhost:8080/test/ServerEndpoint"

after I deploy my project to elastic beanstalk 
I **can't** connect web socket if I use this

> "ws://samplepath.ap-northeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/ServerEndpoint"

this is error message

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

what should I do?